# Visual Studio Class Library Debugging With Intermediate Window

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-standard

In Visual Studio 2022, there is an "Intermediate Window" where, when creating an application, you can evaluate expressions. However, when creating a class library, it pops up with a message box complaining that "A project with an output type of class library cannot be started directly."

This makes sense. After all, the intermediate window works by compiling and running both the application and the function, evaluating the result of the function, and then terminating the program. (At least, that is my understanding.) However, it is rather inconvenient when debugging class libraries.

I found [this MSLearn post](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/1275232/) and [this VSDevCom post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/761932), which testified that it was possible in .NET Framework with the magic of Visual Studio. However, it still doesn't seem to work with .NET Core and .NET Standard.

From the linked posts, I assume this is an error of some sort inside Visual Studio itself. Hopefully, Visual Studio will fix this sometime in the future, but that future may be a very long way away, and I am working on my project now.

So I have three questions.

1. Thousands of people use .NET Core or .NET Standard, thousands of people use Visual Studio, and thousands of people use Visual Studio's intermediate window. Why is there so little discussion about this obvious issue?
2. Is there an immediate workaround for this? I tried creating a console application in the same solution as my libraries (marking it as the startup project), but I got the same error.
3. If the solution to #2 involves creating another project with an executable output type, is there some way to hide that project in the Solution Explorer and when it runs?

Comment: Do you want direct executable output in a class library to run and evaluate expressions like an application